# Minor help page MarkDown error

Tags: bug, status-completed

The [help page for what is on-topic](https://writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) contains the following line:

> ```
> [Requests to rephrase](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/q/535/26) something - a few sentences, or even a single sentence.
> ```

Presumably when edited (by [Neil Fein](https://writers.stackexchange.com/users/26/neil-fein)? He is user 26 as indicated by the share link), the MarkDown was not recognized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for spotting this.  I've fixed it.  (I hadn't realized that the Help Center pages use plain old HTML, not markdown -- and I'll bet Neil didn't notice when making that edit, either.)

Comment: Apparently sometimes when Markdown just plain won't work, HTML will do the job. Thanks for spotting this.

Comment: I only knew that HTML would work because there was other HTML in the page.  It wasn't at all obvious that this editing interface, uniquely?, has different rules.